# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this problem:

> "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

The textbox1 to textbox3 is already running but it stuck in textbox4. I searched for an answer for this error but still can't fix. My code down below. Could anyone help?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DoubleClick
    With DataGridView1

        If .SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = .SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                con = New MySqlConnection
                con.ConnectionString = ServerLocalhost
                con.Open()
                ssql = "select * from bookinformation where BookNumber=" & "'" & DataGridView1.Rows(.SelectedRows(i).Index).Cells(0).Value() & "'"
                dcmd = New MySqlCommand(ssql, con)
                dreader = dcmd.ExecuteReader
                If dreader.Read Then
                    TextBox1.Text = dreader.Item("BookNumber")
                    TextBox2.Text = dreader.Item("BooksTitle")
                    TextBox3.Text = dreader.Item("Quantity")
                    TextBox4.Text = dreader.Item("PublicPrice")
                    TextBox5.Text = dreader.Item("OfficeRemit")
                    TextBox10.Text = dreader.Item("StudentRemit")
                    If inchanged = False Then
                        inchanged = True
                        TextBox7.Text = dreader.Item("SaleFund")
                        TextBox6.Text = dreader.Item("Saving")
                        TextBox8.Text = dreader.Item("SalesPerBook")
                        Label15.Text = dreader.Item("TypeofBook")
                        inchanged = False
                    End If
                    If Label15.Text = ("Hard Bound") Then
                        CheckBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                    ElseIf Label15.Text = ("Paper Bound") Then
                        CheckBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                    ElseIf Label15.Text = ("Complete Set") Then
                        CheckBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                        CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                    Else
                        CheckBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
                        MsgBox("No Type Detected!")
                    End If

                    TextBox1.Enabled = False
                    TextBox2.Enabled = False
                    TextBox3.Enabled = False
                    TextBox4.Enabled = False
                    TextBox5.Enabled = False
                    TextBox10.Enabled = False
                    TextBox7.Enabled = False
                    TextBox6.Enabled = False
                    TextBox8.Enabled = False
                    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
                    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
                    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
                ElseIf id = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("No Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                End If

                '.Rows.RemoveAt(.SelectedRows(i).Index)
            Next
        Else
            ' MsgBox("Please select to Add")
        End If

    End With
```

Comment: If 1-3 works then you probably have a problem with the data in the PublicPrice field and it can't convert it to a string.  If you haven't done so run the query in management studio and inspect the data.  You can try  TextBox4.Text = dreader.Item("PublicPrice").Tostring()  to help you find the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    If dreader.Read Then
    dreader.Read()
```

etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting an answer, a little bit of explanation would be nice so that you can help future visitors understand what this change would do to their programs.